# Vocative comma before "all"?

Tags: vocatives

When using the vocative comma, would it go before "all"?

"Thank you, all, again!"

Or would it be without the comma?

"Thank you all again!"

Is this different from "everybody"?

Comment: I think that using a pair of commas in "Thank you all again!" would be far too heavy-handed for such a small parenthetical. // I don't consider "Thank you, everybody, again!" to be idiomatic. I'd use "Thank you, everybody, once again!" or "Thank you again, everybody!"

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot put a comma between *you* and *all* because they’re a fused set.  *All* works like *both* when modifying *you*. So imagine this:

1 *You* for just one person.
2. *You both* or *you two* for a pair of people.
3. Things like *you all*, *you guys*, *you folks*, *you people* for more than two people. (But careful with the last one; it doesn’t sound good.)

So yes, *you all* is different from *everybody*.  There is no **you everybody*, so that one is an appositive use and takes a comma.

- Thank you, everybody.
- Thanks, you all.
- Thanks, you two.
- I’d like to thank you guys for this.
- I’d like to thank you both for this.

Comment: “You all” doesn’t necessarily _have_ to be a fused set; you could say “Thank you again, all” and be fine, though it does sound a bit old-fashioned.